# basemapのインストールでUnsatisfiableError

Tags: python

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力][image]

python3.6、Windows 8.1でpycharmのsettingの＋を押してbasemapを追加しようとしたり、
githubでwin-64-basemap-1.0.7-np111py27_0.tar.bz2インストール後
コンパイラで
conda install -c anaconda basemap=1.0.7をしました

追伸　python2.7昔入れた記憶がフォルダ検索したところ何もでない

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ。エラー内容を見るにpython2.7とpython3.6が競合しているように見えるのですが、他にどんなものをインストールしているか列挙できますか？

Comment: また、どうやってbasemapをインストールしようとしたかの具体的な説明があると良いかもしれません。

Comment: おそらくその圧縮ファイル win-64-basemap-1.0.7-np111py27_0.tar.bz2 はgithubからダウンロードしたものではないと思います。

Comment: そうですね　一応自己解決できました

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下のコマンドで成功すると思います（ただし1.0.7ではなく1.0.8dev0です）。

```
conda install -c conda-forge basemap=1.0.8dev0
```

---

これはおそらくPython2.x系とPython3.x系の差によるエラーです。質問者さんがコマンド

```
conda install -c anaconda basemap=1.0.7
```

によってインストールしようとしたbasemapはPython2.x系用のもので、それが既に質問者さんの環境にインストールされていたPython3.x系とコンフリクトしたのだと思います。実際、Anaconda cloudの [anaconda/packages/basemap](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/basemap) でFilesを見ても現状Windows用にはPython2.x系のものしか用意されていないように見えます。そこで代わりに [conda-forge/packages/basemap](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/basemap) を使ったというわけです。

補足：1.0.7と1.0.8の違いに関するissueがbasemapのGithubに立っていました。 https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/267

Comment: 同じです　自分もhttps://anaconda.org/conda-forge/basemapからいけました